# releasing Mac apps with wxPython and py2app that work on multiple versions of OS X

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, osx-snow-leopard, py2app

I periodically release a dmg for a Python/wxPython app with py2app, and it has been working great.  I only have access to a Snow Leopard machine and I would like to ensure that my app works on as many versions of OS X as possible.  In the past, I have found that an app created on Snow Leopard worked on Leopard but did not work on Tiger or earlier.

I have two questions:

(1) Can I release a single app that will work on Tiger, Leopard, Snow Leopard, and hopefully Lion?  If so, how?

(2) Does it matter if I use 32 bit or 64 bit Python/wxPython?

Comment: Yes, this should be possible.  Definitely avoid 64-bit if you want to work pre-Snow Leopard, though.  There was no 64-bit GUI support on Tiger and there are quite a few bugs on Leopard.  You might look at the pythonmac-sig mailing list archives; this kind of question has come up a lot.  I haven't ever used wxPython on the Mac so I can't answer any more definitely myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Python from one of the 32-bit-only installers [from python.org](http://www.python.org/download/releases/).  They are built as 32-bit i386 and ppc using a deployment target of OS X 10.3 so they will run on all Apple systems shipped that support any version of OS X 10.3 through 10.6 (and should run on OS X 10.7 when released).  Any C extension modules built with its Distutils (`setup.py`) will be fine.  If they need any 3rd-party C libraries that are not included with Mac OS X, you need to be careful to build and install them in a compatible manner.  The most important thing is to build them as universal builds with `-arch i386` and `-arch ppc`.  Most of the most common libs these days can be made to do that without too much trouble.  Also, to be safe, build them with `gcc-4.0` and `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3` (or `10.4` if that doesn't work).  You'll need Xcode 3, not the newer Xcode 4, and need to install the optional 10.4 SDK from Xcode 3.  Use a wxPython binary installer that meets those criteria and you should be good to go.